# Get last modified date of item added/updated in a site - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to get the date / time stamp for the last item was added / updated to SharePoint site using JavaScript. Is there any API in JS to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the `http://yoursite/_api/web`

It will returns the attribute called "LastItemModified".

Answer (score 4):

Just make a GET request to following URL.

```
{site url}/_api/web/LastItemModifiedDate
```

## Example using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/LastItemModifiedDate",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.d.LastItemModifiedDate);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is a **fetch()** version using **ES6**:
`let url = 'http://www.example.com/yourweb/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Member Your List Name\')/LastItemModifiedDate';

fetch(url,{
 method:'get',
 credentials:'include',
 headers:{
  "Accept":"application/json;odata=nometadata"
 }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json.value))
.catch(error => console.error("Caught Error\n",error))`

Answer (score 3):

- (in Chrome)  Install the SharePoint Insider plugin:
  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sharepoint-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj
- Browse to a (Sub)Web
- See the 2 LastItem** fields with the info you (might) want
- Use the JSON tab to learn how to call the API

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It may not provide the exact answer, but it provides an opportunity to get the answer and more.

Comment: I guess someone does not agree with "Give a SP developer a fish and (s)he will code for a day; teach a SP developer how to fish and (s)he will have a career"

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised nobody mentioned the difference between the `LastItemModifiedDate` and `LastItemUserModifiedDate`. The latter property was added later by Microsoft to reflect changes made by user accounts only. The former property was influenced by changes made by the system.

REST call:

```
sites/.../_api/web/LastItemUserModifiedDate
```

Read about it here:

[Modified dates in Site Contents should reflect content changes, not system changes](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/15112005-modified-dates-in-site-contents-should-reflect-con).

Comment: How's this different from Atish answer?

Comment: There are 2 properties, Atish only mentions the date that is also influenced by system accounts.

Comment: While both LastItemModifiedDate and LastItemUserModifiedDate can be used on the /web level, in SharePoint 2013, it appears only LastItemModifiedDate can be used with a list `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('your list')/LastItemModifiedDate`